# How should I display a full image, without resizing it in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msimg = $("#msbgimage");
    var full = $("#msbgimagefull");
    if (msimg.length && full.length) {
        var imageurl = msimg.css('background-image').replace('url(', '');
        imageurl = imageurl.substring(0, imageurl.length - 1);
        msimg.on('click', function () {
            /*window.open(imageurl, "_blank");*/
            if (full.css('display') == "none")
                full.css('display', 'block');
            else
                full.css('display', 'none');
        });
        full.on('click', function () {
            full.css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.msbgimage
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    max-width:80%;
    max-height:80%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.msbgimagefull
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:White;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:none;
    z-index:1337;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='msbgimage' class='msbgimage' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
<div id='msbgimagefull' class='msbgimagefull' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
```

It will currently resize the image to the device's full screen, meaning it will stretch it and what not.

What I want to do is show the image in its original size with overflow (if needed). Can I do it without knowing the image's size beforehand? If not, how can I do it with the size?

### EDIT:

I managed to show the full image, but now I can't scroll it because it's defined as `position:fixed` because it should cover the whole screen so you can't see what's behind it. How can I fix it so there's are scroll bars for the image?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msimg = $("#msbgimage");
    var full = $("#msbgimagefull");
    var full2 = $("#msbgimagefullp");
    if (msimg.length && full.length) {
        var imageurl = msimg.css('background-image').replace('url(', '');
        imageurl = imageurl.substring(0, imageurl.length - 1);
        var tmp_image = new Image();
        tmp_image.src = imageurl;
        tmp_image.onload = function () {
            full.css('width', this.width);
            full.css('height', this.height);
            msimg.on('click', function () {
                /*window.open(imageurl, "_blank");*/
                if (full2.css('display') == "none")
                    full2.css('display', 'block');
                else
                    full2.css('display', 'none');
            });
            full2.on('click', function () {
                full2.css('display', 'none');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.msbgimage
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    max-width:80%;
    max-height:80%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.msbgimagefull
{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
}

.msbgimagefullp
{
    cursor:pointer;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1337;
    display:none;
    background-color:White;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='msbgimage' class='msbgimage' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
<div id='msbgimagefullp' class='msbgimagefullp'>
    <div id='msbgimagefull' class='msbgimagefull' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be simpler to just use an image element.

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Not sure if this helps.. but here are two different versions of something you may want to do. https://jsfiddle.net/rdLsgd2r/1/

Comment: OR try this one out with overflow toggling. - https://jsfiddle.net/rdLsgd2r/2/

Comment: I edited my question with a new code that can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a new Image object like

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png';
```

then, in the `onload`

```
img.onload = function(){
        $('.msbgimage').css('width', this.width);
        $('.msbgimage').css('height', this.height);
    }
```

Finally, depending on the image size, add

```
background-size:cover;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png';
    img.onload = function(){
        $('.msbgimage').css('width', this.width);
        $('.msbgimage').css('height', this.heightjjjjjj);
    }
    var msimg = $("#msbgimage");
    var full = $("#msbgimagefull");
    if (msimg.length && full.length) {
        var imageurl = msimg.css('background-image').replace('url(', '');
        imageurl = imageurl.substring(0, imageurl.length - 1);
        msimg.on('click', function () {
            /*window.open(imageurl, "_blank");*/
            if (full.css('display') == "none")
                full.css('display', 'block');
            else
                full.css('display', 'none');
        });
        full.on('click', function () {
            full.css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.msbgimage
{
    background-size:cover;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    max-width:80%;
    max-height:80%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:3px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.msbgimagefull
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:White;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:none;
    z-index:1337;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='msbgimage' class='msbgimage' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
<div id='msbgimagefull' class='msbgimagefull' style="background-image:url('http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png')"></div>
```

Comment: Depending on how caching was defined, this may cause the image to be downloaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can if you're setting the size of the div. You can try this:

```
background-size:auto;
```

Or you may need to get the size onload:

```
var img = new Image();
var imgSize = {};
img.onload = function(){
    //Set size
    resizeImg(this.width, this.height)
}


img.src = "url/to/img"
```